# Azure Function App - Python function works with app service plan type consumption, but not with dedicated app service plan

Tags: python, azure, azure-function-app

I have a working Python function app on a consumption (serverless) plan. Version is 3.8. It processes xml files into csv files.
However, the number of xmls to be processed is too high so the function times out after 30 minutes ( I would expect 10 minutes after checking documentation for consumption plans, but wth ).

So I created an identical function to run with a dedicated plan, so that we can have limitless processing time.
When I deploy the function with all necessary modules using the 3.8 interpreter the deployment log tells me the modules are installed successfully.
But when I try to run the function I get "unable to import" errors. It cannot find any of the required modules.
Then I noticed the function seems to be running under python 3.6. It says so in the deployment log and in the error message. But the plan was created for Python 3.8.
I tried changing the python version for the function through the azure cloud shell ( az webapp config set --resource-group xxxxxxx --name xxxappnamexxx --linux-fx-version "PYTHON|3.8" ), but that does not help.

Any ideas on this one ? Could this python version be the reason the modules are not found ?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Question posted to Azure forum:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/39124/azure-functions-always-using-python-36.html